# Python magic method when variable in used as dictionary key

Tags: python, magic-methods

What Python magic method is used to get value when variable in used as dictionary key.

```
dictionary[variable]
```

dictionary is random dictionary,
variable is something like int (my own class)

When i use variable as above, what magic method is used to return the value used as key in dictionary.

Comment: Can you give an example? Your question is unclear

Comment: See the code example...when i use variable as key in dictionary. What method is called in variable.

Comment: My guess is that meant this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68865797/python-magic-function-how-to-change-class-representation-when-the-class-is-a-di